# order item meta in shortcode or move order item meta to different position

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have created custom product styling on woocommerce thank you page. So I have:

```
//not working
add_shortcode('custom_order_meta', 'wc_get_order_item_meta' );

//styling order table with imgs
add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_name', 'custom_product_on_thankyou', 10, 3);


function custom_product_on_thankyou($name, $item, $visible)
{

if (!is_order_received_page()) {
    return $name;
}

$product_id = $item->get_product_id();
$_product = wc_get_product($product_id);
$thumbnail = $_product->get_image();


$thk_product = '
    <div class="checkout-product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-image">' . $thumbnail . '</div>
    <div class="product-content">
        <div class="product-name">' . $name . '</div>
        <div class="product-meta">' . do_shortcode('[custom_order_meta]') .' </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    ';

return $thk_product;
}
```

Is there a way to create shortcode from meta function: wc_get_order_item_meta or: Can I move order item meta in my product-content div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed structure with hooks woocommerce_order_item_meta_start and woocommerce_order_item_meta_end so picture is now on start and now I don't need custom positioning order item meta also don't need hook for order_item_name, only some css to move title and meta from left to right: https://prnt.sc/v89UMQ2_IEr-